# Google VR on static website errors out when deployed to Firebase but works with gh-pages

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, github-pages, firebase-hosting, google-vr

I'm working on a static, Polymer based website. I integrated VR View for the location (map section): https://valleydevfest.com/
Source repo is the `develop` branch: https://github.com/gdgfresno/valleydevfest/tree/develop

The VR View consists of an element, which gets the `url` of the 360 mono image and contains the iframe with the actual VR View: https://github.com/gdgfresno/valleydevfest/blob/develop/src/elements/vr-view.html

```
<template>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <iframe
      frameborder="0"
      width="100%"
      height="250"
      scrolling="no"
      allowfullscreen    
      src="/vrview.html?image=[[url]]&is_stereo=false">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</template>
```

It's used here: https://github.com/gdgfresno/valleydevfest/blob/develop/src/elements/map-block.html#L140

```
<link rel="import" href="vr-view.html">
...
<vr-view
    url="[[_currentImage]]"
></vr-view>
```

Now, this works fine on local development environment served both as `polymer serve`, or when I serve the `unbundled` build directory with `Web Server for Chrome`. But when I deploy it to Firebase the VR View displays the "`Loader: Unable to load scene. Required parameter missing.`" error message. Such error is triggered in VR View when neither `image`, `video`, nor `object` parameter is supplied as a 360 media source. I don't know how is that possible. I also tried to wire in a static URL. (It's another story if I'd have multiple images and it'd start to rotate, Firefox and Edge takes that well while Chrome fails).

The Firebase deployment settings: https://github.com/gdgfresno/valleydevfest/blob/develop/firebase.json

Now, here is the deployment of the build as a gh-pages, source code (the unbundled build directory): https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/mrcsabatoth.github.io and the website: https://mrcsabatoth.github.io/ This works with both Chrome, FF and Edge.

[image]

What is going on?

---

News: I tried to reproduce this in a separate deployment without a custom domain name, and low and behold the VR View element works. So there's something about the custom domain. Maybe related to CORS?

Comment: So far I migrated the site to GitHub gh-pages, but this has one consequence: if you want to use a custom domain, but want to have https (in case of a Progressive Web App you must) that's not supported by vanilla gh-pages out of the box. So I set up free CloudFlare hosting along with it: https://robinwinslow.uk/2016/02/13/free-https-custom-hosting/